# crop and save uploaded image with python and PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i am having a problem crop the uploaded image and save it. I am using Cherrypy.

```
 @cherrypy.expose
 def uploadphoto(self, **data):
    photo = data['photo']
    original_image = Image.open(StringIO(photo.file)) //error happen here
    box = (0, 0, 100, 100)
    cropped_image = photo.crop(original_image)
    path = 'uploads/myphoto.jpg'
    cropped_image.save(path, 'JPEG');
```

here is the form:

```
    <form id="form" action="uploadphoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='file' name="photo"/>
        <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </form>
```

is there anything wrong? i am new to python, please help me out.

Comment: IOError: cannot identify image file <open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x7f25100d9d20>. This is just one error, i tried to play around, and it keep giving different error.

Comment: yes, when i try to print photo.content_type, it returns me: image/png.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "Posting an Edited Photo (This example resizes a photo)" heading on [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-facebook/0.2.0) page.

shouldn't you include .size in the crop line?

like this:

```
    cropped_image = photo.crop(original_image.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file by:

```
photo.file.seek(0)
```